# JSF resources not cached in Liferay portlet

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, liferay

I write a primefaces portlet in Liferay. When view resources loaded with Chrome's Developer tools, I see jsf resources (js, css) not cached.

Example response headers of http://localhost:8080/web/qldt/bao-cao-tinh-hinh-thuc-hien-fdi?p_p_id=BaoCaoDuAnFDI_WAR_qldtportlet&p_p_lifecycle=2&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_cacheability=cacheLevelPage&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1&_BaoCaoDuAnFDI_WAR_qldtportlet_javax.faces.resource=primefaces.js&_BaoCaoDuAnFDI_WAR_qldtportlet_ln=primefaces&v=5.2:

```
Cache-Control:private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:71495
Content-Type:application/javascript;charset=UTF-8
Date:Fri, 31 Jul 2015 02:55:19 GMT
ETag:W/"340248-1432143286996"
Expires:Thu, 29 Oct 2015 02:55:19 GMT
Last-Modified:Wed, 20 May 2015 17:34:46 GMT
Liferay-Portal:Liferay Portal Community Edition 6.1.2 CE (Paton / Build 6102 / August 2, 2013)
portlet.http-status-code:200
Pragma:no-cache
```

But Liferay's resources are work perfectly.

I use: jsf 2.1, primefaces 5.2, liferay 6.1.2, liferayfaces 3.1.2-ga3.

Is there a way to cache jsf resources?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this behavior in [development mode](https://blogs.oracle.com/rlubke/entry/jsf_2_0_new_feature2) or production mode on tomcat. Could you provide more information, namely [the version of Liferay Faces](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/understanding-the-liferay-faces-version-scheme) that you are using and the server you are using?

Comment: @stiemannkj1 Thanks for your respond. I'm using liferayfaces 3.1.2-ga3. I have updated my question.

Comment: Please try upgrading to the latest version of Liferay Faces ([`3.1.5-ga6`](https://www.liferay.com/web/neil.griffin/blog/-/blogs/announcement-liferay-faces-4-x-3-x-2-x-ga6-released)), and see if the issue was fixed.

Comment: @stiemannkj1 I have tried Liferay Faces 3.1.5-ga6 but still not work. If you have time, please try with demo portlet of LIferay Faces http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/liferay/faces/demos/primefaces5-portlet/3.1.5-ga6/primefaces5-portlet-3.1.5-ga6.war

Comment: I cannot reproduce your `no-cache` issue with your portlet (Using Liferay 6.1.2). When I test your portlet, js resources do not have `no-cache` in the headers. Do you have `browser.cache.disabled=true` or `browser.cache.signed.in.disabled=true` in your **`portal-ext.properties`** file?

Comment: @stiemannkj1You right. I have **browser.cache.signed.in.disabled=true** in your portal-ext.properties file. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have **browser.cache.signed.in.disabled=true** in your portal-ext.properties file, so my jsf resources not cached when i logged in.